# Unknown host Exception while calling method " twitter.getOAuthRequestToken()"

Tags: android, twitter, oauth

I am trying to integrate twitter api using library twitter4j-core-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar. But i am getting error Unknown host Exception from 2 days. here is the part of code(index by .....(1)) that is generating Exception.

public  String beginAuthorization() {

```
    //showDialog("Authorization...........");
    //new AuthorizationTask(this).execute("Authorize");

    try {

        if (null == currentRequestToken) {
            Log.e("begin","i am here the line below is throwing excetion");
            currentRequestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();............(1)

        }
        Log.e("beginAuthorization", currentRequestToken.getAuthorizationURL());
        return currentRequestToken.getAuthorizationURL();

    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();


    }

    return null;

}
```

anyone have idea about this problem???

thank u in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I'd forgotten to include in my AndroidManifest.xml:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: i am accepting it as a right answer becoz is one the reason to appear such exception

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you put permission in xml manifest?
2. Have you tried opening a browser in android and going to twitter.com?
3. Try to connect to any url from the code and see what happens.

Comment: thanks for reply. finally i found the reason why it troubling me problem is no INTERNET on emulator though i have wireless network and it is available to desktop. is it proxy problem???

Comment: ya. once, i was able to connect with twitter to fetch status but from the next run i found above problem. problem is that INTERNET in not running on emulator browser though it runs on external browser like chrome etc